# working with large numbers in the fraction module in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, fractions, continued-fractions

EDIT: solved but since the solution was in the comments and I cant accept my own solution reffering to the comment till tomorrow it is still open. Once again a big thank you to this great community and its people

optional context: I am computing sollutions for the Pell equation

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html

On the buttom of the page is a table with values for D -> x, y.
My code works perfectly for EVERY VALUE EXCEPT D = 61. I believe it could have something to do with the values of x and y being very big and maybe the fraction module cant handle such big numbers and there is an overflow?
I made the observation, that whether I give my input/ starting value as a fraction or a decimal changes my solution (but only for D = 61).
Why is my code failing with the value of D = 61? What do I need to change/use to get it to work? Thank you very much for your time and help.

code:

```
from math import sqrt, floor
from fractions import Fraction

def continued_fraction(D):
    # to make sure it is not a problem on converting decimals to fractions I made EVERYTHING a fraction (which shouldnt and didnt affect the output)
    # input is the value for D, output is a tuple with (x, y)
    D = Fraction(sqrt(D))
    aS = []
    a0 = D
    r1 = Fraction(D - floor(D))
    a = Fraction(a0 - r1)
    r = Fraction(-1)
    count = 0
    while a <= 2*floor(D):
        aS.append((a, count))
        if a == 2*floor(D):
            if count % 2 == 0:
                break
            else:
                r = count
        if count == 2*r:
            break
        try:
            a0 = Fraction(1/r1)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            break
        r1 = Fraction(a0 - floor(a0))
        a = Fraction(a0 - r1)
        count += 1
    pS = []
    qS = []
    a0 = Fraction(floor(D))
    p0 = a0
    p1 = Fraction(a0 * aS[1][0] + 1)
    q0 = Fraction(1)
    q1 = Fraction(aS[1][0])
    count = 2
    while count < len(aS):
        pS.append((p0, count - 2))
        qS.append((q0, count - 2))
        pn = Fraction(aS[count][0] * p1 + p0)
        qn = Fraction(aS[count][0] * q1 + q0)
        p0 = Fraction(p1)
        p1 = Fraction(pn)
        q0 = Fraction(q1)
        q1 = Fraction(qn)
        count += 1
    pS.append((p0, count-1))
    #pS.append((p1, count))
    qS.append((q0, count - 1))
    #qS.append((q1, count))
    #print(pS)
    #print(qS)
    return Fraction(pS[-1][0]), Fraction(qS[-1][0])
print(continued_fraction(Fraction(61)))
```

Comment: If you have any questions please contact me.

Comment: The solution is [here](https://projecteuler.chat/viewtopic.php?t=1572)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I still got 2 problems:
1. My program gives neither solution "A", nor solution "B" (why?)
2. I already had a feeling, that it might be an overflow error (now I am quite sure) but I still dont know how to fix it/how to fix it in Python. Ints in Python have unlimited size but what about the fraction module? And what could I do to fix the overflow with the fraction module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big thanks to GalAbra and jasonharper for your responds. After knowing with certainty, that it is a percision problem (thank you GalAbra) I knew I needed more decimals for the sqrt(D). I used the decimal module from Python:

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 1000
D = Fraction(Decimal(D).sqrt())
```

with this and the change suggested by jasonharper (thank you again) it works now.

Answer (score 2):

`Fraction(1/r1)` means to compute the reciprocal of `r1` as an inexact floating-point number, and then find a rational approximation of that inexact number.  You want `Fraction(1, r1)` to directly specify the numerator and denominator of your fraction, without any approximation errors creeping in.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but I changed it and it still yields the same (wrong) result.